# Insert records if not exist to specific columns with special conditions in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a CSV file which i'd like to insert into a table (let's call it ***my_table***).

For this task, I load the CSV file into a new temporary table called ***temp_table*** (has the same features/structure as ***my_table***). The values that don't exist should be INSERTED into ***my_table***
However there are certain conditions that must be fulfilled:

if a value in column letter in ***my_table*** doesn't exist then:

1. insert the value in 'letter' into the column letter in ***my_table***
2. also insert 'num' value into the column num in ***my_table***

if the value 'letter' exists, but the value in 'num' is missing in ***my_table*** , UPDATE that record in the column 'num'

Here is an example for a table in temp_table (left) and my_table (right):

```
    temp_table                my_table



    letter   num            letter   num
    1  aab     123            aab      123 
    2  aac     123            ---      ---  (both don't exist)
    3  bba     234            bba      ---  (only num doesn't exist)

                result my_table:

                  letter     num 
                 1 aab      123 
                 2 aac      123    
                 3 bba      234
```

*order (id) doesn't matter.

EDIT: so you can see that the value in line 1 isn't inserted to ***my_table*** because the value aab already exists.
in the second line, aac doesn't exist and therefore it is inserted together with the value of num. 
in the third line, bba needs to be updated, where the column num gets the value.

does anyone knows how to do it in MySQL?

or would it be easier/make more sense to try to write in PHP?

**ADDITIONAL:**
This is what I came up so far in order to overcome part 1 -

```
INSERT INTO my_table (letter) 
SELECT DISTINCT letter FROM temp_table 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_table.letter = temp_table.letter);
```

The above mentioned does the job partially. It inserts values that do not exists in letter only. But what about part two? inserting the rows of the column **num** in which rows in letter are missing? Like in row 2 of the example..
for that purpose I tried:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (letter, num) 
SELECT DISTINCT letter, num FROM temp_table 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_table.letter = temp_table.letter 
AND my_table.num = temp_table.num);
```

however, that didn’t work as I wanted.
Although it did skip the first row and indeed inserted the row (2) as it should have:

```
2  aac     123
```

it however also inserted the row:

```
letter     num 
1  aab      123 
2  aac      123    
3  bba     
4  bba      234
```

as a new row, and that shouldn’t have occurred! because bba already exists and that is the condition for part 3.

so as mentioned before, the value for the column num should be inserted, **if and only if** the row in column **letter** EXISTS !!

Comment: Do you want an upsert?

Comment: Hi, well I actually want to insert without duplicates. but I guess that I need also where the value in letter already exists, but not on num

Comment: Can you explain it in other way? In the given example, is exactly what it's being done, inserting the second record/line and updating the third.

Comment: Ok. I added an edit with an example

Comment: for the person who reduced a point on this question.. why? instead, why not offering a solution?!   or at least explain yourself!

Comment: @Apython, don't worry about drive-by downvotes without explanation. Haters will be haters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a UNIQUE constraint on `letter` then you can use MySQL's [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax, with a little bit of logic for your `num` column:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (letter, num) 
SELECT letter, num FROM temp_table 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  num = COALESCE(num, VALUES(num));
```